# How to edit my SVN account in Zend Studio

Tags: svn, zend-framework, zend-studio

I am working on Zend Studio and using Subversion.

Since yesterday, my account is no longer accepted; I get errors like: "the account is not matching"...

Can someone tell me how we edit a svn account in Zend Studio? The colleague who installed svn is missing!

pas de chance

Answer (score 0):

Go to Preferences and open the Source Control tab.
Choose a Source Control Tool Subversion there are menus for options.